# mtpro2 installation for MacTeX2016 (OS X Sierra)

Tags: mtpro

I am attempting to install mtpro2 fonts using the instructions at

http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/

Here is the mtpro2-texlive.sh.log

```
mtpro2-texlive.sh log file.
Wed May 31 00:01:20 CDT 2017
TeX information:
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
updmap.cfg is at /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
The texmf directory for fonts is /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
confirm_input(): Checking mtpfonts.zip.tpm.
File does not exist.
```

Do I have my files in the wrong location in the directory?  The .sh and .tpm files are in my home directory /Users/...

Comment: I don't know why you need an installer. Anyway: As the intructions clearly says you need first to get the real fonts from pctex. Did you do this? And if yes did you pass the correct path to the font file when calling the script?

Comment: Yes I do have the fonts purchased from pctex.  The fonts from pctex are in Users/brianhons/mtpro2-texlive-v1-1 along with the installer.  I typed commands exactly from http://cims.nyu.edu/~fennell/mtpro2/ except I have mtp2fonts not mtp2lite.